# local-function-key-map gets overwritten by emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient, keymap

The following `.emacs` file works as expected, so long as I invoke emacs the "normal" way (ie by launching the `emacs` executable directly).

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-]"))
(global-set-key (kbd "H-C-]") 'abort-recursive-edit)
(define-key local-function-key-map (kbd "C-]") 'event-apply-hyper-modifier)
```

But when I start emacs via `emacsclient -n -c -a  ""`, the value of `local-function-key-map` gets overwritten somewhere along the way.  I have used print statements to make sure that my `.emacs` file is getting run, and that the value of `local-function-key-map` gets updated.  But by the time I land in the `*scratch*` buffer, my binding is missing from `local-function-key-map`.

Has anyone experienced this before, or knows a reason why `local-function-key-map` would get clobbered when starting emacs via `emacsclient`?

I am running emacs-25.1 on CentOS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(n.b. Refer to nispio's answer for details of why this approach can solve the problem.)*

I use `after-make-frame-functions` when dealing with terminal-local settings.

e.g.:

```el
;; Per-frame/terminal configuration.
(defun my-frame-behaviours (&optional frame)
  "Make frame- and/or terminal-local changes."
  (with-selected-frame (or frame (selected-frame))
    ;; do things
    (message "new frame %S" (selected-frame))
    ))
;; Run now, for non-daemon Emacs...
(my-frame-behaviours)
;; ...and later, for new frames / emacsclient
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-frame-behaviours)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was really surprised that there was not a hook for that.  I forgot that hooks occasionally get named `-functions` instead of `-hook`.  Any idea if there is a reason for the difference?  Or is it random?

Comment: Quoting `(elisp) Hooks`: "If the hook variable’s name does not end with `-hook`, that indicates it is probably an “abnormal hook”.  That means the hook functions are called with arguments, or their return values are used in some way.  The hook’s documentation says how the functions are called.  You can use `add-hook` to add a function to an abnormal hook, but you must write the function to follow the hook’s calling convention.  By convention, abnormal hook names end in `-functions`."

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

`local-function-key-map` is a terminal-local version of `function-key-map`, so defining my binding in `function-key-map` fixed the problem

## Why?

The reason for the behavior seems to be that `local-function-key-map` is a terminal-local variable.  When using `emacsclient`, two distinct terminals are created: one in the tty, and one for the X-windows. Calling `(terminal-list)` after starting emacs via `emacsclient` returns this:

`(#<terminal 0 on initial_terminal> #<terminal 1 on :0>)`

So `local-function-key-map` in "terminal 0" (the tty) has my binding defined, but the one in "terminal 1" (the graphical frames) does not.

None of the following hooks seemed to run *after* the new terminal-local definition of `local-function-key-map` had been created.

```
after-init-hook
before-make-frame-hook
tty-setup-hook
term-setup-hook
emacs-startup-hook
```

So finally, I ended up using `local-function-key-map`'s parent map, `function-key-map`, because it is not terminal-local.  I still find it strange that I cannot find a way to automatically modify `local-function-key-map` after a new terminal is created.