# Using Emacs as a daemon (emacsclient) exhibiting weird behavior

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, emacsclient, emacs-daemon, daemon

Whenever I use Emacs as a daemon it seems like my init file isn't being fully loaded.

My keybindings in particular are acting very odd.


I use some unorthodox keybinds; for example:

<kbd>Ctrl+u</kbd> = `beginning-of-buffer` and <kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd> = `end-of-buffer`

But now when using Emacs as a daemon they revert to their default behavior (`universal-argument` and `insertline` respectively).


Is my `init.el` file not loading correctly when my computer boots up?

If so, is there a way to modify the `emacs.service` file to fix this problem?

## EDIT 1 (Suggested by Phil in the comments)

**emacs.service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(progn (setq kill-emacs-hook nil) (kill emacs))"
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStartSec=0
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**keybindings.el file (This file is too large to show everything, so I'm just going to show a couple bindings, also note that this file gets imported into my `init.el` file)**

```
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-o")  (kbd "<control-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-u")  (kbd "<control-u>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<control-o>")       'end-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<control-u>")       'beginning-of-buffer)
```

Note that the above binds **DO NOT** work when I'm running emacsclient (as well as other binds), but they **DO** work when I'm running Emacs regularly without a server.

## EDIT 2

I think I may have found a clue at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/537922/how-do-i-get-my-emacs-init-files-to-load-correctly-with-emacs-server

## EDIT 3 (Suggested by Tyler in the comments)

**keybindings.el file**

```
(provide 'keybindings)

(global-unset-key (kbd "M-i"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-k"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-j"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-l"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-u"))
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-o"))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-i") 'previous-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-k") 'next-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'backward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-l") 'forward-char)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-u") 'back-to-indentation)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'end-of-line)

;;; Functions pertaining to simple binds
(defun jd-scroll-down ()
  "Scrolling down conditional for buffers and minibuffers."
  (interactive)
  (if (minibufferp)
      (ivy-scroll-down-command)
    (scroll-down-command)))

(defun jd-scroll-up ()
  "Scrolling up conditional for buffers and minibuffers."
  (interactive)
  (if (minibufferp)
      (ivy-scroll-up-command)
    (scroll-up-command)))

(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-a")  (kbd "<control-a>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-b")  (kbd "<control-b>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-d")  (kbd "<control-d>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-e")  (kbd "<control-e>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-f")  (kbd "<control-f>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-h")  (kbd "<control-h>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-i")  (kbd "<control-i>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-j")  (kbd "<control-j>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-k")  (kbd "<control-k>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-l")  (kbd "<control-l>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-m")  (kbd "<control-m>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-n")  (kbd "<control-n>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-o")  (kbd "<control-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-p")  (kbd "<control-p>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-q")  (kbd "<control-q>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-r")  (kbd "<control-r>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-s")  (kbd "<control-s>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-t")  (kbd "<control-t>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-u")  (kbd "<control-u>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-w")  (kbd "<control-w>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-y")  (kbd "<control-y>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-;")  (kbd "<control-scolon>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-,")  (kbd "<control-comma>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-.")  (kbd "<control-period>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-/")  (kbd "<control-slash>"))

(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-a")  (kbd "<meta-a>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-b")  (kbd "<meta-b>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-c")  (kbd "<meta-c>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-d")  (kbd "<meta-d>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-e")  (kbd "<meta-e>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-f")  (kbd "<meta-f>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-g")  (kbd "<meta-g>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-h")  (kbd "<meta-h>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-i")  (kbd "<meta-i>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-j")  (kbd "<meta-j>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-k")  (kbd "<meta-k>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-l")  (kbd "<meta-l>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-m")  (kbd "<meta-m>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-n")  (kbd "<meta-n>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-o")  (kbd "<meta-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-p")  (kbd "<meta-p>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-q")  (kbd "<meta-q>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-r")  (kbd "<meta-r>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-s")  (kbd "<meta-s>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-t")  (kbd "<meta-t>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-u")  (kbd "<meta-u>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-v")  (kbd "<meta-v>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-w")  (kbd "<meta-w>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-y")  (kbd "<meta-y>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-z")  (kbd "<meta-z>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-;")  (kbd "<meta-scolon>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-,")  (kbd "<meta-comma>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-.")  (kbd "<meta-period>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-/")  (kbd "<meta-slash>"))

(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-a")  (kbd "<control-meta-a>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-b")  (kbd "<control-meta-b>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-c")  (kbd "<control-meta-c>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-d")  (kbd "<control-meta-d>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-e")  (kbd "<control-meta-e>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-f")  (kbd "<control-meta-f>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-g")  (kbd "<control-meta-g>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-h")  (kbd "<control-meta-h>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-i")  (kbd "<control-meta-i>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-j")  (kbd "<control-meta-j>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-k")  (kbd "<control-meta-k>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-l")  (kbd "<control-meta-l>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-m")  (kbd "<control-meta-m>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-n")  (kbd "<control-meta-n>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-o")  (kbd "<control-meta-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-p")  (kbd "<control-meta-p>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-q")  (kbd "<control-meta-q>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-r")  (kbd "<control-meta-r>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-s")  (kbd "<control-meta-s>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-t")  (kbd "<control-meta-t>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-u")  (kbd "<control-meta-u>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-v")  (kbd "<control-meta-v>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-w")  (kbd "<control-meta-w>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-x")  (kbd "<control-meta-x>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-y")  (kbd "<control-meta-y>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-z")  (kbd "<control-meta-z>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-;")  (kbd "<control-meta-scolon>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-,")  (kbd "<control-meta-comma>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-.")  (kbd "<control-meta-period>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-/")  (kbd "<control-meta-slash>"))

(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-a")  (kbd "<control-shift-a>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-b")  (kbd "<control-shift-b>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-c")  (kbd "<control-shift-c>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-d")  (kbd "<control-shift-d>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-e")  (kbd "<control-shift-e>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-f")  (kbd "<control-shift-f>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-g")  (kbd "<control-shift-g>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-h")  (kbd "<control-shift-h>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-i")  (kbd "<control-shift-i>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-j")  (kbd "<control-shift-j>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-k")  (kbd "<control-shift-k>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-l")  (kbd "<control-shift-l>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-m")  (kbd "<control-shift-m>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-n")  (kbd "<control-shift-n>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-o")  (kbd "<control-shift-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-p")  (kbd "<control-shift-p>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-q")  (kbd "<control-shift-q>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-r")  (kbd "<control-shift-r>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-s")  (kbd "<control-shift-s>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-t")  (kbd "<control-shift-t>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-u")  (kbd "<control-shift-u>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-v")  (kbd "<control-shift-v>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-w")  (kbd "<control-shift-w>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-x")  (kbd "<control-shift-x>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-y")  (kbd "<control-shift-y>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-z")  (kbd "<control-shift-z>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-;")  (kbd "<control-shift-scolon>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-,")  (kbd "<control-shift-comma>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-.")  (kbd "<control-shift-period>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-S-/")  (kbd "<control-shift-slash>"))

(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-a")  (kbd "<meta-shift-a>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-b")  (kbd "<meta-shift-b>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-c")  (kbd "<meta-shift-c>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-d")  (kbd "<meta-shift-d>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-e")  (kbd "<meta-shift-e>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-f")  (kbd "<meta-shift-f>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-g")  (kbd "<meta-shift-g>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-h")  (kbd "<meta-shift-h>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-i")  (kbd "<meta-shift-i>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-j")  (kbd "<meta-shift-j>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-k")  (kbd "<meta-shift-k>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-l")  (kbd "<meta-shift-l>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-m")  (kbd "<meta-shift-m>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-n")  (kbd "<meta-shift-n>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-o")  (kbd "<meta-shift-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-p")  (kbd "<meta-shift-p>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-q")  (kbd "<meta-shift-q>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-r")  (kbd "<meta-shift-r>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-s")  (kbd "<meta-shift-s>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-t")  (kbd "<meta-shift-t>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-u")  (kbd "<meta-shift-u>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-v")  (kbd "<meta-shift-v>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-w")  (kbd "<meta-shift-w>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-x")  (kbd "<meta-shift-x>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-y")  (kbd "<meta-shift-y>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-z")  (kbd "<meta-shift-z>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-;")  (kbd "<meta-shift-scolon>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-,")  (kbd "<meta-shift-comma>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-.")  (kbd "<meta-shift-period>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-S-/")  (kbd "<meta-shift-slash>"))

(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-a")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-a>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-b")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-b>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-c")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-c>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-d")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-d>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-e")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-e>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-f")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-f>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-g")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-g>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-h")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-h>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-i")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-i>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-j")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-j>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-k")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-k>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-l")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-l>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-m")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-m>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-n")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-n>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-o")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-o>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-p")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-p>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-q")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-q>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-r")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-r>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-s")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-s>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-t")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-t>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-u")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-u>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-v")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-v>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-w")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-w>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-x")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-x>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-y")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-y>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-z")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-z>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-;")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-scolon>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-,")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-comma>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-.")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-period>"))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-S-/")  (kbd "<control-meta-shift-slash>"))

....
```

## ATTEMPT 1 (As suggested by Phil in the comments)

**init.el file**

```
(defun my-debord-translations (&optional frame)
  "Re-map keys in the current terminal."
  (require 'keybindings "/home/i/.emacs.d/keybindings.el"))
;; Evaluate both now (for non-daemon emacs) and upon frame creation
;; (for new terminals via emacsclient).
(my-debord-translations)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-debord-translations)
```

## ATTEMPT 2

**init.el file**

```
(require 'keybindings "/home/i/.emacs.d/keybindings.el")

;; Evaluate both now (for non-daemon emacs) and upon frame creation
;; (for new terminals via emacsclient).
(my-debord-translations)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-debord-translations)
```

**keybindings.el file**

```
(provide 'keybindings)

....

(defun my-debord-translations (&optional frame)
  "Re-map keys in the current terminal."
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-a")  (kbd "<control-a>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-b")  (kbd "<control-b>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-d")  (kbd "<control-d>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-e")  (kbd "<control-e>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-f")  (kbd "<control-f>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-h")  (kbd "<control-h>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-i")  (kbd "<control-i>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-j")  (kbd "<control-j>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-k")  (kbd "<control-k>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-l")  (kbd "<control-l>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-m")  (kbd "<control-m>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-n")  (kbd "<control-n>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-o")  (kbd "<control-o>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-p")  (kbd "<control-p>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-q")  (kbd "<control-q>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-r")  (kbd "<control-r>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-s")  (kbd "<control-s>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-t")  (kbd "<control-t>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-u")  (kbd "<control-u>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-w")  (kbd "<control-w>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-y")  (kbd "<control-y>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-;")  (kbd "<control-scolon>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-,")  (kbd "<control-comma>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-.")  (kbd "<control-period>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-/")  (kbd "<control-slash>"))

   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-a")  (kbd "<meta-a>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-b")  (kbd "<meta-b>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-c")  (kbd "<meta-c>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-d")  (kbd "<meta-d>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-e")  (kbd "<meta-e>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-f")  (kbd "<meta-f>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-g")  (kbd "<meta-g>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-h")  (kbd "<meta-h>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-i")  (kbd "<meta-i>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-j")  (kbd "<meta-j>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-k")  (kbd "<meta-k>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-l")  (kbd "<meta-l>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-m")  (kbd "<meta-m>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-n")  (kbd "<meta-n>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-o")  (kbd "<meta-o>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-p")  (kbd "<meta-p>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-q")  (kbd "<meta-q>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-r")  (kbd "<meta-r>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-s")  (kbd "<meta-s>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-t")  (kbd "<meta-t>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-u")  (kbd "<meta-u>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-v")  (kbd "<meta-v>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-w")  (kbd "<meta-w>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-y")  (kbd "<meta-y>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-z")  (kbd "<meta-z>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-;")  (kbd "<meta-scolon>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-,")  (kbd "<meta-comma>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-.")  (kbd "<meta-period>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "M-/")  (kbd "<meta-slash>"))

   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-a")  (kbd "<control-meta-a>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-b")  (kbd "<control-meta-b>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-c")  (kbd "<control-meta-c>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-d")  (kbd "<control-meta-d>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-e")  (kbd "<control-meta-e>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-f")  (kbd "<control-meta-f>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-g")  (kbd "<control-meta-g>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-h")  (kbd "<control-meta-h>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-i")  (kbd "<control-meta-i>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-j")  (kbd "<control-meta-j>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-k")  (kbd "<control-meta-k>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-l")  (kbd "<control-meta-l>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-m")  (kbd "<control-meta-m>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-n")  (kbd "<control-meta-n>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-o")  (kbd "<control-meta-o>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-p")  (kbd "<control-meta-p>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-q")  (kbd "<control-meta-q>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-r")  (kbd "<control-meta-r>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-s")  (kbd "<control-meta-s>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-t")  (kbd "<control-meta-t>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-u")  (kbd "<control-meta-u>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-v")  (kbd "<control-meta-v>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-w")  (kbd "<control-meta-w>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-x")  (kbd "<control-meta-x>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-y")  (kbd "<control-meta-y>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-z")  (kbd "<control-meta-z>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-;")  (kbd "<control-meta-scolon>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-,")  (kbd "<control-meta-comma>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-.")  (kbd "<control-meta-period>"))
   (define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-M-/")  (kbd "<control-meta-slash>")))

....
```

Comment: Show us this "emacs.service" file (and maybe mention how it's used); and show us the config which isn't working.  At the moment you've basically said "Something doesn't work; how do I fix that?"

Comment: Ok I updated the question.

Comment: A four line excerpt of your init file isn't much to go on.There's likely something going on before you get to this section, since this is the bit that *doesn't* run for you. There's no way to tell what the problem might be. You're going to have to start bisecting your init file to narrow down where the problem is. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: @Tyler Ok I updated the question including the whole file to get a better picture. Many of the CTRL keys don't work, but the META keys do; no errors in my init file.

Comment: The Q&A you linked to is correct.  `input-decode-map` is a terminal-local variable, so your code *only* affects the current 'terminal' at the time the daemon runs -- so when you actually create a frame of your own, those bindings are not seen.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31359/454 is an effective duplicate -- you can use the same technique of using `after-make-frame-functions` to configure `input-decode-map` in every terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [local-function-key-map gets overwritten by emacsclient](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/local-function-key-map-gets-overwritten-by-emacsclient) -- different keymap, but the exact same issue.  Just make the `input-decode-map` bindings inside the custom function.

Comment: See also [Multiple Terminals](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multiple-Terminals.html) in the manual.

Comment: @phils Ok so I edited my question with my first attempt based off of the resources you have given. The first attempt did not work. Gonna keep trying.

Comment: @phils Tried it. It didn't work. I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: @JohnDeBord check the link again (n.b. I changed what I was initially linking to), and make sure you're using the `with-selected-frame` wrapper.

Comment: And definitely don't use `require` in the *body* of your `after-make-frame-functions` callback -- the whole purpose of `require` is to **not** load the library if it was previously loaded.  (Your "Attempt 2" looks good in this respect, and so possibly just needs that `with-selected-frame` added.)

Comment: @phils Yayayaya it worked! #FirmHandshakes

Comment: 1. The question is now a mess. If you think it is a helpful question for other, please consider paring it down to just the essential question. 2. If you now have the answer, as it seems, please post the answer and accept your answer. 3. If you think your question and answer are not helpful for others, please delete the question. Thx.